# SWF Investigator can't parse some DefineFont3 tags

Tags: fonts, flash

I wow parsing a swf file with SWF Investigator and some other tools when I found that the DefineFont3 tags cannot be parsed. Different tools give different errors. However, Adobe Flash Player and Sothink Decomplier could recognise it. So is there anybody help me looking into this problem? It'd be very nice of you.

Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n02lbplm77exmhp/page003.swf

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Adobe Flash Player reads the offsetTable first, then look up the glyphShapeTable for a given character when encountered. So some SWF may have glyphShapeTable not immediately following codeTableOffset or vacancies between glyphShape entries, however, as the SWF provided correct offsetTable, it can be recognised by Adobe Flash Player.